# average within an array

Tags: arrays, vba, average

I am looking for a way to elegantly average within a 2D array.  I have code that works for a small range of elements but I need something that I can use for a large number of elements.

Here is the code I have for a small number of elements.  This code will average 3 elements on the same row and return the answer to a results array.  How can I rewrite this if 50 elements?  As you can imagine this approach will not work well for a large number of elements.

```
    For i = 1 To UBound(TMP)
                results(i, 1) = ((TMP(i, 13) + TMP(i, 14) + TMP(i, 15)) / 3)
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

You would move the desired values into a 1D array, then use the application.Average() function.  For example:

```
Dim rwarr() As Double

For i = 1 To UBound(TMP, 1)
    ReDim rwarr(1 To UBound(TMP, 2)) As Double
    For j = 1 To UBound(TMP, 2)
        rwarr(j) = TMP(i, j)
    Next j
    results(i, 1) =  Application.Average(rwarr)
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that can take the average of multiple columns in each row of a 2-D array.

```
Public Function AverageRowsIn2DArray(Arr As Variant, LBoundCol As Integer, UBoundCol As Integer) As Variant
    Dim iNumValues As Integer
    iNumValues = UBoundCol - LBoundCol + 1
    If iNumValues < 1 Then GoTo ErrHandler
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim retArr As Variant
    Dim inArr As Variant
    If TypeName(Arr) = "Range" Then
        inArr = Arr.Value
    Else
        inArr = Arr
    End If

    ReDim retArr(1 To UBound(inArr), 1 To 1)

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim dSum As Double

    For i = 1 To UBound(inArr)
        dSum = 0
        For j = LBoundCol To UBoundCol
            dSum = dSum + inArr(i, j)
        Next j
        retArr(i, 1) = dSum / iNumValues
    Next i

    AverageRowsIn2DArray = retArr
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    AverageRowsIn2DArray = 0
End Function
```

In your specific case, you would want to call

```
Dim results() as Double
results = AverageRowsIn2DArray(TMP, 13, 15)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Scott!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Function Scott.  I did modify it slightly to limit the input to a single row.  It's working great!! Thank you.  Here is the modified Function:

```
Public Function AverageRowsIn2DArray(Arr As Variant, Nrow As Integer, LBoundCol As Integer, UBoundCol As Integer) As Variant
    Dim iNumValues As Integer
    iNumValues = UBoundCol - LBoundCol + 1
    If iNumValues < 1 Then GoTo ErrHandler
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim retArr As Integer
    Dim inArr As Variant
    If TypeName(Arr) = "Range" Then
        inArr = Arr.Value
    Else
        inArr = Arr
    End If

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim dSum As Double


    For i = LBoundCol To UBoundCol
        dSum = dSum + inArr(Nrow, i)
    Next i
    retArr = dSum / iNumValues


    AverageRowsIn2DArray = retArr
    Erase inArr
    retArr = 0
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    AverageRowsIn2DArray = 0
End Function
```

now my call is,

```
results(i, 4) = AverageRowsIn2DArray(TMP, i, 13, 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have less than 30K elements in the first rank, use the [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) to peel off a row to process an [AVERAGE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGE-function-047BAC88-D466-426C-A32B-8F33EB960CF6) from.

```
Sub avgVals()
    Dim tmp As Variant, results As Variant, a As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                tmp = .Cells.Value2
            End With

            ReDim results(LBound(tmp, 1) To UBound(tmp, 1), 1 To 1)
            For a = LBound(tmp, 1) To UBound(tmp, 1)
                results(a, 1) = Application.Average(Application.Index(tmp, a, 0))
            Next a

            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, .Columns.Count)
                .Cells.Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
            End With

        End With


    End With
End Sub
```

Using the [Excel Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx) to facilitate INDEX slicing an array apart is not the fastest method and ultimately it has limiations but it can provide an expedient method of achieving your [AVERAGE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGE-function-047BAC88-D466-426C-A32B-8F33EB960CF6) results for smaller batches.